# When using angular-ui-router, what is the suitable structure for controller?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Before use angular-ui-router, one controller always support several router&views, such as:

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/posts', {
        templateUrl: 'views/posts/list.html'
    }).
    when('/posts/create', {
        templateUrl: 'views/posts/create.html'
    }).
```

all views for one object share one controller:

```
app.controller('PostsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.create = function() {
    // ...
  }
  $scope.list = function() {
    // ...
  }
});
```

and init data in view:

```
<div data-ng-controller="PostsController" data-ng-init="list()">
  ...
</div>
```

But in angular-ui-router, we use state, so we need create several controller for each state, such as:

```
$stateProvider
  .state('posts', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/posts',
    templateUrl: 'views/posts/list.html',
    controller: 'PostsCtrl'
  })
  .state('posts.detail', {
    url: '/:postId',
    templateUrl: 'views/posts/detail.html',
    controller: 'PostsDetailCtrl'
  })
```

Separating controller seems not a good design pattern.

So, is there any better suggestion to structure controllers?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is...? Controllers should be written specific to the parts of the UI they control. The smaller and more focused, the better (to a point, obviously; I find around 5-6 methods each is the ideal size).

Answer (score 2):

It is a little late for an answer, but as I was struggling with it and found an answer, I might as well post it.

I agree with Nate's comment that in most circumstances you should keep the controllers as small as possible, i.e. you should write a separate controller for every state. However, if you find yourselves in a situation that really think that using the same controller for both the parent and child views is preferable you can simply omit the `controller` option in the child view. This view will then use the state of the parent. This can be read in the [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#wiki-nested-states--views). A little example:

### app.js

```
app.controller('testController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.message= 'This comes from testController';
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider ,$urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('test', {
      url: '/test',
      templateUrl: 'partials/test.html',
      controller: 'testController'
    })
    .state('test.child', {
      url: '/child',
      templateUrl: 'partials/test2.html'
    });
}]);
```

### partials/test.html

```
<div>
    Test.html: {{message}}
    <div data-ui-view></div>
</div>
```

### partials/test2.html

```
<div>
    Test2.html: {{message}} as well.
</div>
```

This will produce the following (with url `#/test/child`)

```
Test.html: This comes from testController
Test2.html: This comes from testController as well.
```

I hope this helps anyone